# Error: faceting variables must have at least one value

Tags: r, plotly, powerbi, facet

I have the following dataset:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
4439.5  6.5211  50.0182 29.4709 -0.0207 0.0888
4453    25.1186 46.5586 34.1279 -0.0529 0.082
4453.5  24.2974 46.6291 30.6281 -0.057  0.0809
4457.5  25.3257 49.6885 26.2664 -0.0357 0.0837
4465    7.1077  53.516  32.5077 -0.0398 0.1099
4465.5  7.5892  53.0884 33.1582 -0.0395 0.1128
4898.5  8.8296  55.0611 40.3813 -0.0123 0.1389
4899    9.2469  54.4799 37.1927 -0.0061 0.1354
4900    13.4119 50.8334 28.9441 -0.0272 0.1071
4900.5  21.8415 50.1127 24.2351 -0.0375 0.0882
4905    11.3824 52.4024 37.2646 -0.0324 0.1215
4918.5  6.2601  49.9454 27.715  0.0101  0.1444
4919    7.4157  49.7412 25.6159 -0.0164 0.1038
4932    25.737  46.2825 38.6334 -0.0425 0.0717
5008.5  13.641  49.7868 18.0337 -0.0213 0.111
5010.5  13.5935 49.5352 23.9319 -0.0518 0.0979
5012    16.6945 48.0672 25.2408 -0.0446 0.0985
5014.5  14.1303 49.6361 23.1816 -0.0455 0.1056
5040    7.6895  49.8688 31.562  -0.0138 0.126
5044    12.594  60.822  52.4569 0.0481  0.1877
5045.5  10.3719 56.443  43.3782 0.0076  0.1403
5046    8.1382  54.5388 46.2675 0.01    0.1443
5051.5  29.0142 46.8052 43.3224 -0.0465 0.0917
5052    32.3053 46.4278 32.9387 -0.0509 0.0868
5052.5  38.4807 45.3555 24.4187 -0.0619 0.0774
5053    38.8954 43.8459 21.8487 -0.0688 0.0681
5055    19.69   50.9335 46.9419 -0.0527 0.0897
5055.5  11.7398 51.8329 59.5443 -0.0307 0.1083
5056    13.3196 51.8329 55.4419 -0.0276 0.1262
5056.5  18.3702 51.7003 39.232  -0.0408 0.1105
5057.5  14.0531 50.1129 24.4546 -0.0444 0.0921
5058    15.292  49.8805 23.0938 -0.0347 0.0925
5059    20.5135 49.52   21.6173 -0.0333 0.1006
5060    14.5151 47.5836 27.0685 -0.0156 0.1062
5060.5  14.5188 48.2506 27.9704 -0.0363 0.1018
5228    1.2168  54.2009 17.4351 0.0583  0.1794
5229    3.5896  51.7649 26.1107 -0.0033 0.1362
5232.5  2.7404  53.5941 38.6852 0.0646  0.194
5233    3.6694  53.9483 36.674  0.0633  0.204
5234    1.3789  53.8741 18.5804 0.0693  0.1958
5234.5  0.8592  53.6052 18.1654 0.0742  0.1982
5237    2.6951  52.3763 24.8098 0.0549  0.1923
```

I am trying to create an R visual that will break out each Column into facets, using Col1 as the identity column.

To do this I am using this (faulty) code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)

plot.data <- dataset
melted <- melt(dataset, id.vars="Col1") 



sp <- ggplot(melted, aes(x=Col1, y=value)) + geom_line()

# Divide by variable in the vertical direction
sp + facet_grid(variable~.)

ggplotly()
```

However, I am receiving an error saying:

> ```
> Faceting variables must have at least one value
> ```

Comment: Works for me. Tried updating everything and starting from a clean R workspace?

Comment: So I'm doing this in Power BI, not in R itself, but since you said it worked for you, I tried it in R and it also worked for me... must be a Power BI issue. I actually just copied and pasted the same table twice in pBI and when I'm connected to Table1 it doesn't work, but for some reason Table2 does work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an unlikely solution, but did you make sure all your filters are correct / not filtering out values somehow? I find that filter are often a source of mistakes for me so if it works in R, that could be the problem.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was my filtering:
Example:
I did this `data <- data[data$symbol == geneId,]`  instead of `data <- data[data$symbol %in% geneId,]`